# Using authentication proxy in wcf services not working

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authentication, proxy

I have a WCF Client which has several services, most of them use a CustomBinding and one of the services uses `BasicHttpBinding`. I have been trying to configure my client to pass through a Proxy which requires authentication and uses the NTLM protocol for the last couple of days. I have read countless posts and pages suggesting different methods to get this done but none of them have worked so far.

For now i'll be focusing on getting the `BasicHttpBinding` to work which seems to be the easiest one.

When using a Browser like Chrome or Edge the authentication with the proxy works without problems. When inspecting the traffic with Fiddler, i can see the [NTLM protocol handshake](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html):

> ```
> 1: C  --> S   GET ...
>
> 2: C <--  S   407 Proxy Authentication Required
>               Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
>
> 3: C  --> S   GET ...
>               Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-1-message>
>
> 4: C <--  S   407 Proxy Authentication Required
>               WWW-Authenticate: NTLM <base64-encoded type-2-message>
>
> 5: C  --> S   GET ...
>               Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-3-message>
>
> 6: C <--  S   200 Ok
> ```

However, WCF does not seem to be doing anything when receiving Message **#2**, and the service call fails with the exception that:

> Proxy authentication is required

I am also not able to handle this exception and try to invoke the service again, adding the Authorization header manually, because I do not know how to get the type-1 message required by the proxy. Even if I could create the message manually, I would expect that WCF should have support for these kind of scenarios, it should work seamlessly.

I have tried:

- Configuring the binding to use the default proxy and default credentials (`UseDefaultProxy` and `UseDefaultCredentials`) both programmatically and using the `app.config`.
- Setting the `ProxyAddress` of the binding programmatically, while also setting the Credentials.
- Modifying the `ProxyCredentialType` of the Binding
  (`BasicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType`) to use
  NTLM, Windows, and other options.
- Changing the `BasicHttpBinding.Security.Mode` to
  BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
- Setting the    `ClientCredentials` of the Endpoint Behaviour, while also
  setting the    `ClientCredentials.Windows` credentials.

None of these modifications worked, nor changed the message created by WCF (as verified in fiddler) it never sends any credentials, nor communicates with the proxy, and when it receives the proxy authentication required message (which is part of the NTLM protocol) WCF fails to respond to this message and the service call returns with an exception.

How can I make so that WCF automatically handles this interaction with the proxy seamlessly?